# Chrome Offlining with workbox deletes cache on system restart

Tags: javascript, restart, offline-caching, workbox

I have tried to create a webpage that I want to cache (contains heavy assets like lengthy videos and images). I followed the workbox guides to the point and the offlined app works as intended. However on system restart, when I open the app, the cache no longer exists and the app makes network calls to get the data. I would understand if the app reset its cache via a code, however, the moment I open the app, the cache simply isn't there.

My guess is that there is a flag/setting on the `Cache API` that I am missing or some system-level setting on my chrome that is triggering this behavior.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Chrome Version: `Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

OS:

```
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="19.2 (Tina)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 19.2"
VERSION_ID="19.2"
HOME_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
VERSION_CODENAME=tina
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

> Note: Tried this on Windows, same behavior occurs

Comment: im pretty sure videos dont get cached for long if at all, else it would quickly fill up cache/hdd

Comment: I am using the standard cache API, total size so far is 300mb, is that a lot?